# What is the difference in using angular vs angular-nativescript components

Tags: android, angular, mobile, nativescript, nativescript-angular

It seems I can use both, but what is the advantage of using each for android development?

Comment: What you mean by Angular vs Nativescript Angular components? Nativescript Angular or Vue were introduced to allow web developers who are familiar with these frameorks to reuse their skillset and eventually share their code between web and native mobile apps. Even if you are not familiar with these framework it's wise to pick one up as it gives you a lot of features out of the box which you might have to do on your own when using Nativescript Core.

Comment: There exist the legacy angular components from google itself like angular material. But there also exist the UI-Widgets from angular-nativescript: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics click on the "UI Widgets" menu link then many components are listed.

Answer (score 0):

**NativeScript !== Cordova**

NativeScript doesn't host your app inside a WebView. Your UI is totally native here. For example when you create a button that is not a HTML button but it is the [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) (iOS) / [android.widget.Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) (Android).

With their JavaScript runtime, you get 100% access to all the iOS / Android native apis. So you can reuse your web skills like XML / JavaScript / CSS and frameworks like Angular / Vue to build a pure native app. You may even share controller / model code (not HTML) between your web and mobile app.

Since the components you specified are based on HTML, you will not be able to use them in NativeScript. You have use it's native UI widgets.